Error: "Profiles use this record type as default" when attempting to delete or deactivate a record type."
Error: "Profiles use this record type as default" when attempting to delete or deactivate a record type.
According to the Salesforce article https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385230&type=1, this error appears with the message: "This record type cannot be deleted/deactivated because the following profiles use this record type as default." Despite following the steps provided, we are still encountering this issue, particularly with the Chatter profiles.
Please advise on further steps to resolve this.

This question is similar to: Remove Record Type from Chatter Profiles. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
